# Homotopy is an equivalence relation

Tags: homotopy-theory

I am trying to prove that for all spaces $X$ and $Y$, homotopy is an equivalence relation on the set of maps from $X$ to $Y$. In my book they say if $f: X \to Y$, then $f \simeq_F f$ where $F(x,t) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and $t \in I$. I am wondering how we know that $F$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $f$ since it must be a continuous function $F: X \times I \to Y$ such that $$F(x,0) = f(x), F(x,1) = g(x), \quad \text{and} \quad F(*,t) = *.$$ How do we prove that $F(x,t)$ is a continuous function? Must we show that the preimage of any open set is open?

Answer (score 1):

Answering strictly your question at the end (not the full proof of "homotopy is an equivalence relation" - still leaving that to you to complete).

Consider the function $p:X \times I \to X$, $p(x, t) = x$. Show that THIS function is continuous (preimage of an open set is that set $\times I$, which is open in the product topology). Then $F = f \circ p$ and the composite of continuous functions is continuous.

This is a very common theme in mathematics - try to decompose "harder" problems into smaller, "we know that..." kind of pieces, and then combine them. The smaller pieces aren't that numerous; it's only the immense number of combinations of such things that makes math seem difficult. (OK, and sometimes you do need to come up with clever tricks...)

Comment: Does the projection have a basepoint and preserve it during composition?

Comment: No, and it doesn't need to. The projection is only used in your proof of "$F$ is continuous," you don't need it for anything else.

Comment: If it is a homotopy it must preserve the basepoint so how do we know that $F$ does?

Comment: If $x_0$ and $y_0$ are the fixed points and $f(x_0) = y_0$, then $F(x_0, t) = f(x_0)$ (by definition) which $ = y_0$.

Comment: These are assumed to be based maps so $f(x_0) = x_0$

Comment: Seriously? With $f:X \to Y$? What if $x_0 \not \in $Y$?

Comment: A fixed point $x_0$ is chosen in the topological space $X$.